# Insert many to many using entity c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am trying to insert a new relation many to many to my application:

I have resources and I want them to be able to have dependencies beetween each other.

In my DbContext, I added the following code:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Resource>()
            .HasMany(e => e.ResourceChildList)
            .WithMany(e => e.ResourceParentList)
            .Map(m => m.ToTable("LinkResourceResource").MapLeftKey("ResourceIdParent").MapRightKey("ResourceIdChild"));
```

This created perfectly my new table "LinkResourceResource" in base.

I added a ResourceChildList and ResourceParentList

I have now a unit test for the update of resources; In this test I create 2 resources in base and i try to connect each other in the update.

**DEBUG**

When I enter in the update method, here is the dto passed:

```
{Resource}
Id: 487
InternalReference: null
IsDelete: false
Matriculation: null
Name: "Resource Test2"
ResourceChildList: Count = 1
ResourceParentList: Count = 0
ResourceState: Available
ResourceSubtypes: Count = 1
SerialNumber: "Resource Test2"
```

and here is the child in ResourceChildList:

```
Id: 488
InternalReference: "Child"
IsDelete: false
Matriculation: "child"
Name: "Child"
ResourceChildList: Count = 0
ResourceParentList: Count = 1
ResourceState: Available
ResourceSubtypes: Count = 0
SerialNumber: "Child"
```

In fact, when I pass in the update, I have the following error:

```
Failed to attach an entity of type "Entities.Resource" because another entity of the same type already has this primary key value. This can happen when you use the "Attach" method, or you set the status of an entity to "Unchanged" or "Modified" if any features in the chart have conflicting key values. Some entities may be new and may not have received key values ​​generated by the database yet. In this case, use the "Add" method or the "Added" entity to draw the graph, then set the "Unchanged" or "Modified" value to the state of entities other than new entities.
```

I spent a hole day trying to solve this, I dont understand why he tries to create a new resource. Does somebody understands?

Thank you

**EDIT**

here is the code used for create/attach

```
Resource resourceEntity=await Context.Set<Resource>().AsNoTracking().Include(nameof(Resource.ResourceParentList), nameof(Resource.ResourceChildList)).FirstAsync(o => o.Id == 487);

Resource resourceChild= await Context.Set<Resource>().AsNoTracking().Include(nameof(Resource.ResourceParentList), nameof(Resource.ResourceChildList)).FirstAsync(o => o.Id == 488);

resourceEntity.ResourceChildList.Add(resourceChild);

Context.Entry(resourceEntity).State = EntityState.Modified;

await Context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: You maybe should add the code where you  create/attach and save the entities

Comment: The code would be very usefull, please also verify that you either attach a resource which you loaded with your context or that you add a correct id to the property.

Comment: edited the question.

Comment: Why are you loading the entity objects with `AsNoTracking()`? Is a disconnected scenario needed in your case?